# Getting the results of a Haskell script from Java

Tags: java, haskell

I'm trying to create a program to compare the amount of time it takes various haskell scripts to run, which will later be used to create graphs and displayed in a GUI. I've tried to create said GUI using Haskell libraries but I haven't had much luck, especially since I'm having trouble finding up to date GUI libraries for Windows. I've tried to use Java to get these results but either get errors returned or simply no result.

I've constructed a minimal example to show roughly what I'm doing at the moment:

```
    import java.io.*;
public class TestExec {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ghc test.hs 2 2");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Haskell script this is calling, in this case a simple addition:

```
test x y =  x + y
```

Currently there simply isn't any result stored or printed. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Create executable first and then run it in `exec`

Comment: You also need a `main` in your haskell code.

Comment: You are telling Haskell that `test x y` is the same as `x + y`. What output do you expect?

Comment: You should also use `runghc` rather than `ghc`

Comment: Such benchmark won't produce any reliable results. 'Test' function executes instantly. Thus your benchmark will only measure how long does it take in your OS to start an executable.

Comment: @user2894391 This is only a minimal example, in the actual program two large strings are processed, and the processing code itself is rather complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're attempting to run this as an executable, you need to provide a main. In you're case it should look something like

```
import System.Environment

test :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
test = (+)

main = do
  [x, y] <- map read `fmap` getArgs
  print $ x `test` y
```

This just reads the command line arguments, adds them, then prints them. Though I did something like a while ago, it's much easier to do the benchmarking/testing in Haskell, and dump the output data to a text file in a more structured format, then parse/display it in Java or whatever language you like.

Comment: I get an error when trying to compile this: Couldn't match type [Char] with Char, Expected type IO String, Actual type IO [String] (in the second argument of `fmap`).
I had considered having one Haskell script do all the benchmarking etc for each other script in the directory, but wasn't sure if it would be simpler than this way or not. I'll probably look back into that though, thanks for the tip

Comment: Thanks. Another quick question that I didn't think warranted another full question: Using a variation of the code posted above I want to read two arguments but one is a string and the other an integer, however I get type mismatch errors when compiling. Is there a way to tell haskell to read X as an Int and y as a String?

Comment: @fylth remove the `map read ` part and instead of `test x y` do `test (read x) y`

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly a Java question. Search for [Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+Runtime.getRuntime+exec).

On the Haskell side, you need to write a stand-alone Haskell script. [The one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20474463/25450) by @jozefg is OK. You should be able to run it as

```
runghc /path/to/script.hs 1 2
```

from the command line.

Calling it from Java is no different than running any other external process in Java. In Clojure (a JVM language, I use it for brevity) I do:

```
user=> (def p (-> (Runtime/getRuntime) (.exec "/usr/bin/runghc /tmp/test.hs 1 2")))
#'user/p
user=> (-> p .getInputStream input-stream reader line-seq)
("3")
```

Please note that I use `runghc` to run a script (not `ghc`). Full paths are not necessary, but could be helpful. Your Java program can be modified this way:

```
--- TestExec.question.java
+++ TestExec.java
@@ -2,7 +2,7 @@
 public class TestExec {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
-            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ghc test.hs 2 2");
+            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/runghc /tmp/test.hs 2 2");
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                 new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
             String line = null;
```

The modified version runs the Haskell script just fine. You may have to change paths to you `runghc` and `test.hs` locations.

Answer (score 0):

At first to read from output you need to use `OutputStreamReader(p.getOutputStream())` instead of `InputStreamReader`

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment such a benchmark is simply incorrect. While benchmarking one should eliminate as many side coasts as possible. The best solution is to use the [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) package. It produces nice graphical output as you desire.

Small example:

```
import Criterion
import Criterion.Main
import Criterion.Config

fac 1 = 1
fac n = n * (fac $ n-1)

myConfig = defaultConfig {
              cfgReport = ljust "report.html"
             }

main = defaultMainWith myConfig (return ()) [
           bench "fac 30" $ whnf fac 30
          ]
```

After execution it produces a file "report.html" with neat interactive plots.